# how to make a dataframe out of a dictionary where each column is a list of values?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, dictionary

i have a dictionary where each key is a number (index) and each value is a list of words (strings). I want to create a df with two columns, one for the index number from the dictionary key and one for the list of words (values in the dictionary). Right now I am using this code:

```
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(tok_red_dict, orient ='index')
```

but this is giving me a data frame with a column for the index and a column for each word in the list of words. how can i make it so each column contains the entire list rather than just one word?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], as well as the current and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want this?

```
d = {'test_1': [1,2,3],
     'test_2': [5,6,7]}
df = pd.DataFrame([d]).T.reset_index()

#or

df = pd.Series(d).to_frame().reset_index()
```

output:

```
    index   0
0   test_1  [1, 2, 3]
1   test_2  [5, 6, 7]
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `pd.Series()` to input the dict and then transform from Pandas Series to DataFrame, as follows:

```
tok_red_dict = {101: ['cat', 'dog'], 120: ['pig', 'fox', 'wolf'], 231: ['elephant', 'eagle', 'fish', 'cow']}

df = (pd.Series(tok_red_dict)
        .to_frame(name='word list')
        .rename_axis(index='dict key')
     ).reset_index()
```

Result:

```
print(df)

   dict key                     word list
0       101                    [cat, dog]
1       120              [pig, fox, wolf]
2       231  [elephant, eagle, fish, cow]
```